# WCF with .Net and other clients?

Tags: wcf, .net-4.0

What is a good way to create a WCF service layer so that a native .Net client application and other client types can talk to the service?

I know, in the future our applicaiton will need to support mobile devices.

We are passing objects into our WCF methods similar to this:

```
    [DataContract]
    public class User: DomainBase
        {
            [DataMember]        
            public string Username { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string Password { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string FirstName { get; set; }
            [DataMember]
            public string LastName { get; set; }
}
```

So there may be a method in our servcie like this:

```
public bool Save(User item){
   ...do some work
}   

public User GetUserByUsernameAndPassword(string username, string password){
   ...do some work
}
```

Now, in .Net I can use the same object library as my services, but with other clients I will not be able to. So, if I don't want to write a bunch of differnt methods for each type of client what would be the best way to handle this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think interoperability with other clients is more dependent on the binding that the actual contracts. If the other clients and client languages that you will support can do SOAP, then sticking with the `BasicHttpBinding` provides the best support. For example clients using .NET 2 can still interact with a .NET 3.5 WCF server. There area also SOAP libraries for Java and other languages.

The server can just publish the WSDL, and the clients can then generate all your contract interfaces and types automatically in whatever language from the WSDL. That handles the 'reuse' of your data contract types.

If you want to venture away from SOAP, there are ways to do REST or Plain-old-XML or JSON with WCF, but it gets a lot more complicated from the server side...

Comment: I know, in the past, working with a Java based client, I had to go with the basicHttpBinding. Nothing else would work.

Answer (score 1):

What you have now should work perfectly for any other client. What leads you to believe there might be a problem?

Comment: Well, I haven't played around with many other client types and wanted to get an opinion. I guess the represenation of the data objects is my concern.Let's say I have one client using a XMLHTTPRequest and another talking .Net. I don't really want to pass a SOAP envelope, but know JSON will work great for the HTTP request, and at the same time want the .Net app to pass the actaul object. Can I do all that with jsut one method in ym service? What kind of bindings do I need for the XMLHTTPRequest?

Comment: @DDiVita: you don't understand. SOAP is standard. It will "just work". Even your .NET clients are using standard protocols to access the data.

Comment: You're right. I guess I may be over thinking this. I have been reading alot about the Request type attributes you can put on an operation and that may be throwing me off. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

It depends on which binding you choose to support. Certain bindings only work with .NET.

- BasicHttpBinding: SOAP over HTTP. Any SOAP client can connect
- WsHttpBinding: - It is same like
  BasicHttpBinding. In short, it uses
  SOAP over HTTP. But with it also
  supports reliable message transfer,
  security and transaction. WS-Reliable
  Messaging, security with WS-Security,
  and transactions with WS-Atomic
  Transaction supports reliable
  message.
- NetTcpBinding: - This
  binding sends binary-encoded SOAP,
  including support for reliable
  message transfer, security, and
  transactions, directly over TCP. The
  biggest disadvantage of NetTcpBinding
  is that both server and client should
  be also made in .NET language.
- NetNamedPipesBinding:-Ths binding
  Sends binary-encoded SOAP over named
  pipes. This binding is only usable
  for WCF-to-WCF communication between
  processes on the same Windows-based
  machine.